# Mask R-CNN: How are the computed masks projected back to the input image?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, instance-segmentation, mask-rcnn

The computed masks by Mask R-CNN are of fixed size $m \times m$ each. How are they projected back to the image?

Comment: Is this the same question as your previous one [https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/34551/2444](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/34551/2444)? If not, can you clarify why. If yes, I recommend that you delete one of the two.

Comment: No it's a different question, about how the masks are back-projected to the input image.

Answer (score 0):

Each computed mask is simply resized to the corresponding computed bounding-box. For example, using OpenCV:

```
mask = cv2.resize(mask, (bboxW, bboxH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Then, after converting it to a binary mask by thresholding it, you can overlay this mask on the input image using the coordinates of the corresponding computed bounding-box.

See [here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/19/mask-r-cnn-with-opencv/) for more details.